# select 10 day old entries BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to get only entries that are 10 days + old in BigQuery, I went to other questions and google doc (which is confuse as hell) but could not find a the result I expected.

My query:

```
SELECT Id
FROM myTable
WHERE eventTS > TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 10 DAY)
```

The this query is returning values that are not 10 days + old.

when I add  `-10 DAY` doesn't return nothing.

Any help is MUCH welcome!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing `>` with `<`:

```
SELECT Id
FROM myTable
WHERE eventTS < TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 10 DAY)
```

Comment: When I do that, `This query returned no results.` (and there is rows 10 days + old :( )

Comment: Could you show us some of the expected rows?

Comment: Hey @Sergey Geron thank you for your answer! I had a mistake in my BigQuery that's why I did not got any values, after solving it your solution worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try following Bigquery functions `SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() as Curr_Ts, TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 10 DAY) as Sub_Ts , TIMESTAMP_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL -10 DAY) as Add_Ts` It will Add & Substract 10 days from CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(). Output will be as :-

[image]

Your Query will get modified as :-

```
SELECT Id
FROM myTable
WHERE eventTS < TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 10 DAY)
```

Or

```
SELECT Id
FROM myTable
WHERE eventTS < TIMESTAMP_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL -10 DAY)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for explain! Your answer helped me a lot! I'll accept the fist answer because it solved my problem at the end, but thank you for taking the time to elaborate this answer!

Comment: Great!! All the best.